# To add to the sandboxing idea

Tags: feature-request, sandbox

The [riddle sandbox](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/the-riddle-sandbox) was created recently to improve the quality of riddles on the site until a specific standard is set. Riddles posted which have not been sandboxed are put on hold, with an explanation of what sandboxing is.

Would it be possible to have a [Sandboxing] tag in the title of the question, instead of the simple [on-hold] tag? This would add some extra clarity i think, and increase awareness of the sandboxing process.

Answer (score 3):

It's a great idea, but it's not something that can be accomplished without code changes to the website, which are very unlikely to happen, especially given the "temporary" nature of the sandbox.

It also isn't necessarily appropriate.  Most people who have posted their riddles to Main and have had them put on hold go on to post them to the sandbox, but there may be people who don't think it's worth the effort, and just abandon their riddle.  The tag in this case would be misleading.

It would be conceivable to manually edit in the [Sandboxing] tag where appropriate, but I doubt anyone wants to take on responsibility for that.  If you want to do it for your own riddle questions, I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: If the sandboxing tag existed, i would volunteer to do this for a while