# What should we do with the answers in the sandbox after the riddles have been posted on the main site?

Tags: discussion, sandbox

Yesterday, I believe I have read, on [The Riddle Sandbox](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5276/25964), that a riddle reaching a vote of 7 could make it to the main site. So far, so good. And I remember that the sandbox answer should be cleaned, leaving only the title of the riddle linked to main site, and the answer deleted. I could not find that mention today. What is the suggested course of action?

Comment: As a side note, it's likely that the sandbox will soon [no longer be required](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31992243#31992243) - it'll still be there for people who want help crafting their riddles, but not a requirement before posting riddles to the main site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official procedure.  The status quo has been to delete them from the sandbox when they're posted on main.  This has the benefits of:

1. Keeping clutter in the sandbox to a minimum (it has a *lot* of answers)
2. Keeping people who see the puzzle on main from going to the sandbox to try to find the answer (or clues to the answer).

The downside of this is that the revision history and comments of the riddle are lost, so no one can see how the riddle was improved and learn from the process.

Comment: Understood. What about a separate Sandbox archive for that purpose?

Comment: So should I just delete it, or keep the title only before deletion?

Comment: @Laurent What's generally been done is to edit the answer so that it is a single line (something like "This riddle has been posted on the main site"), and then delete it. That way, the people who have the ability to view deleted questions won't have to scroll through quite as much content to find the still-active answers.