# Should we have a sandbox?

Tags: discussion, sandbox

Should we have a sandbox for Puzzling like we do for Code Golf?

I will count your answer as correct just for your opinion.

Comment: There's one for riddles, are you suggesting a separate sandbox for anything that isn't a riddle?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To expand on my comment, which apparently got deleted when the question was migrated, Puzzling.SE [already has a sandbox](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/the-riddle-sandbox). It's not as active as the one on PPCG, and I don't know whether all kinds of puzzles are accepted there, but it exists nonetheless.